# How to remove protocols from link dialog (ckeditor)

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, dialog, ckeditor, protocols

I want to remove the option for the "other" dialog in ckeditor (links -> protocol).

It's confusing for the user; they don't specify a protocol, then the link looks for a file on my server (instead of an external link, confusing the user).

I tried removing the "other" option from link.js, but that didn't work (still shows up). If I remove it from the language files, I get "undefined" instead of other. I've tried searching for everything like "ckeditor remove link protocol" without luck.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution - by making changes to the config.js file. (I always look for hours, finally decide to ask SO, then get a new idea and find the solution only a bit later >< )

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
{
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
    // interested in (the 'link' dialog).
    if ( dialogName == 'link' )
    {
        dialogDefinition.getContents('info').get('protocol')['items'].splice(4, 1);
```

This part is somewhat well documented. Google search for "removing dropdown options" was more succesful.

`dialogDefinition.getContents()` gets the tab

`get('protocol')` gets the input item

`['items'].splice(4, 1)` gets the item property of the object returned above, and removes the last element from the list (I think I could use pop but whatever). So there's nolonger the `other` option.

Comment: See: http://skvare.com/blog/remove-tabs-and-elements-from-ckeditor-dialog-window for a good example of customizing the link dialog.

Answer (score 4):

We had similar issue and we also removed the other option from the dropdown list.

Modify the following text in the link.js file from the plugins\link\dialog folder

```
items:[['http://‎','http://'],['https://‎','https://'],['ftp://‎','ftp://'],['news://‎','news://'],[E.other,'']]
```

with this

```
items:[['http://‎','http://'],['https://‎','https://'],['ftp://‎','ftp://'],['news://‎','news://']]
```

and it should work fine. See the screen shot below

[image]

Comment: Strange, that was my first attempt and it did not work. I fixed it another way below, but thanks for the suggestion [+1]!

Comment: This did not work for me either until I realised that the file was cached.  For those after me, make sure you clear your cache after you change link.js...CTRL+F5 did not work for me, I had to clear in in IE Dev Toolbar

Answer (score 4):

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
{
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
    // interested in (the 'link' dialog).
    if ( dialogName == 'link' )
    {
    // Remove the 'Target' and 'Advanced' tabs from the 'Link' dialog.
    dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'target' );
    dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'advanced' );

    // Get a reference to the 'Link Info' tab.
    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        infoTab.remove( 'protocol');

    }
});
```

Put the above code in config.js of ckeditor plugin